# Python IN operator for List comparision

Tags: python, list, contains

I am working with Python plugins.
I have my list called `station_list` ,to which i had appended all the values.It contains all the integer values.
Now,I wanted to check my query result with list content. My code is:

```
self.db._exec_sql(c, "select distinct (station) from station  ")
for row in c.fetchall():
    for m in range(len_station_list):
        print row[0],station_list[m]

        if row[0] == station_list[m]:
                print 'true'
```

I am checking each selected row with list values. When i print and check, it gives correct answer.But comparision goes wrong.
It does not satisfy condition `if row[0] == station_list[m]:`.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the output from the `print row[0],station_list[m]` line, so we can see why the `if` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
x = self.db._exec_sql(c, "select distinct (station) from station  ").fetchall()

y = [p for p in x if p[0] in station_list]
```

Comment: Thanx for helping..p[0] checks for only one row.How to check for all rows?? and what does y contains??

Comment: @user1111283 That's not true. `p[0]` checks for the first member (field) of each row. `y` contains all rows for which the first member is in your `station_list` - which should better be a `set`, not a list.

Comment: @user1111283 the code in `[ ]` brackets is called a list comprehension - it will iterate through all the items in x and build a list containing all items in p where p[0] is in station_list.